# Why didn't I get my tag badge for [featured] tag?

Tags: support, tag-badges

I [have 23 answers with total score of 247](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:259214+[featured]) in the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). Why didn't I get a badge for it (I know that those scores and badges would disappear after [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) is removed from the only question it is applied to in some time, but now I am *just* wondering)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68395) :

> - A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be considered for tag badges.

Sorry, but as cool as a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) badge would be, it's unlikely to ever qualify.

Comment: Heh, dumb me :D have your free reps :D